# magento2: conditional rewrite the template

Tags: magento2, template

I am rewriting the search block but i want it to conditional based on system configuration. If module is enabled then it will rewrite the template otherwise default will be loaded.

```
<referenceBlock name="top.search">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Spacename_Moduelname::form.mini.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
<referenceBlock name="top.search">
    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="contact/contact/enabled">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Spacename_Moduelname::form.mini.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Here `contact/contact/enabled` is equal to `section/group/variable`

Answer (score 0):

Since `<action>` tag is deprecated, it's better to create a plugin for `getTemplate()` method for the desired block.